# Vagrant command fails, but not if run by hand

Tags: vagrant

I built my first Vagrant box.

When I `vagrant up` the box I get this error:

```
tange/centos3.3 Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
tange/centos3.3 ==> default: Importing base box 'tange/centos3'...
tange/centos3.3 ==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
tange/centos3.3 ==> default: Setting the name of the VM: centos3_default_1598053704177_14223
tange/centos3.3 ==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2203.
tange/centos3.3 ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
tange/centos3.3 ==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
tange/centos3.3     default: Adapter 1: nat
tange/centos3.3     default: Adapter 2: hostonly
tange/centos3.3 ==> default: Forwarding ports...
tange/centos3.3     default: 22 (guest) => 2203 (host) (adapter 1)
tange/centos3.3 ==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
tange/centos3.3 ==> default: Booting VM...
tange/centos3.3 ==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
tange/centos3.3     default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2203
tange/centos3.3     default: SSH username: vagrant
tange/centos3.3     default: SSH auth method: private key
tange/centos3.3     default: 
tange/centos3.3     default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
tange/centos3.3     default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
tange/centos3.3     default: 
tange/centos3.3     default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
tange/centos3.3     default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
tange/centos3.3     default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
tange/centos3.3 ==> default: Machine booted and ready!
tange/centos3.3 ==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
tange/centos3.3     default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
tange/centos3.3     default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
tange/centos3.3     default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
tange/centos3.3     default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
tange/centos3.3     default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
tange/centos3.3     default: your host and reload your VM.
tange/centos3.3     default: 
tange/centos3.3     default: Guest Additions Version: 4.3.8
tange/centos3.3     default: VirtualBox Version: 6.1
tange/centos3.3 ==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
tange/centos3.3 The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
tange/centos3.3 Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
tange/centos3.3
tange/centos3.3 /sbin/ip -o -0 addr | grep -v LOOPBACK | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/://'
tange/centos3.3
tange/centos3.3 Stdout from the command:
tange/centos3.3
tange/centos3.3
tange/centos3.3
tange/centos3.3 Stderr from the command:
tange/centos3.3
tange/centos3.3 bash: line 1: ip: command not found
tange/centos3.3 bash: line 1: ifconfig: command not found
```

It seems the system cannot find neither `ip` nor `ifconfig`, but when I login as `vagrant` the commands work just fine. And if I run:

```
/sbin/ip -o -0 addr | grep -v LOOPBACK | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/://'
```

I get a list of network interfaces.

So why does it work when I run it by hand, but not when Vagrant tries to?

How can I change the box so this does not happen?

Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "tange/centos3"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # NOTE: This will enable public access to the opened port
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine and only allow access
  # via 127.0.0.1 to disable public access
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.27.27.3"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
    vb.memory = "512"
  end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    ssh_pub_key = File.readlines("../../authorized_keys").first.strip
    s.inline = <<-SHELL
      mkdir /root/.ssh
      echo #{ssh_pub_key} >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
      echo #{ssh_pub_key} >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
      sudo apt install rsync || sudo yum install -y rsync || sudo pkg install -y rsync
    SHELL
  end
end
```

```
$ vagrant --version
Vagrant 2.2.9
```

Comment: There is also an [issue ticket about this on Github](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/11843).

Answer (score 0):

There is an old and unresolved issue opened at Hashicorp, which indicates that CentOS, no matter how much it updates the repository, does not update the Base Box that has an old kernel.
The problem is that the plugin needs a package from the same Box kernel version, but this package, CentOS has already removed from the repo.

You need to add in your Vagrantfile the instruction for vbguest to update the kernel, or use an old version of the vagrant-vbguest plug:

```
config.vbguest.installer_options = { allow_kernel_upgrade: true }
```